# Consulta usando between com sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou fazendo uma consulta utilizando o operador `Between` para selecionar um intervalo de datas, no banco de dados SQL Server 2005. Abaixo estão os dados da tabela `Servico`:

```
linha1: 2015-02-04 14:51:01.577
linha2: 2015-02-04 14:51:02.137
linha3: 2015-02-04 14:51:04.810
linha4: 2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
linha5: 2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
linha6: 2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
linha7: 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
linha8: 2015-01-20 00:00:00.000
linha9: 2015-01-20 10:20:44.000
linha10: 2015-01-20 10:20:44.200
```

Pretendo selecionar o intervalo '20/01/2015' a '04/02/2015' com as queries:

```
select * from Servico
WHERE convert(datetime,dataServico,103) between '04/01/2015' and '04/02/2015'

ou

select * from Servico
WHERE convert(datetime,dataServico,103) >= '04/01/2015' and 
      convert(datetime,dataServico,103) <= '04/02/2015'
```

As duas *queries* retornam os dados abaixo:

```
linha4: 2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
linha5: 2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
linha6: 2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
linha8: 2015-01-20 00:00:00.000
linha9: 2015-01-20 10:20:44.000
linha10: 2015-01-20 10:20:44.200
```

O grande problema é que não retorna as linhas 1,2 e 3. Como solucionar essa consulta ou então fazer de outra forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está a comparar o tipo *Date* com o tipo *Datetime*. O segundo parâmetro, em termos de *Datetime*, é considerado como `04/02/2015 00:00:00.000`, que é o inicio do dia. Para que a consulta inclua o dia todo faça assim:

```
select * from Servico
WHERE convert(datetime,dataServico,103) between '04/01/2015' and '04/02/2015 23:59:59'
```

Comment: ramaral, obrigado pela ajuda funcionou perfeitamente.